# Stop Ubuntu 20.04 from writing automatically in exponent after "^": a¹ --> a^1

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout

How can I stop Ubuntu 20.04 from automatically writing in exponent after using "^"? I know I can press the space bar to avoid this but it's getting quite annoying.

Instead of a¹ I want to write a^1. But without having to press the space bar every time.

I saw a similar question from a few years ago. Someone said I can change this behaviour in settings -> keyboard. However there is only a "keyboard shortcuts" option in my settings which is not useful.

Comment: Which keyboard layout are you using?

Comment: The layout is just "German" (When I look under seetings -> Language and Region)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the *German (dead grave acute)* keyboard layout.